# How to test JS private methods in Ruby on Rails without changing any code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby on Rails application and I want to know if there exists a Gem or a way to test JS functions which are private, in Rails without changing any source code.

I tried to make them accessible by Teaspoon and Sinon, but they change the source code. In Node.js, there exists something like Rewire and was wondering if similar solutions exist for RoR.

Comment: What do you mean you "[not to] change the code to make it accessible by Teaspon and Sinon"? You are meant to add some code right? so needs to be "changed" right? However, if what I'm getting is correct: that you all already have a testing-framework (rspec or cucumber?) in Rails, and that somehow you "changed" the test suite, by adding Teaspoon and Sinon, and that you want to revert back, and just use rspec or cucumber? I am not too knowledgeable about JS testing in Rails, but I'd imagine you'll need like that: Teaspoon, because Rails is agnostic of JS as it is meant to be tested in Ruby.

Comment: Is your company using GitHub? Well if so, why dont you just download the latest version and then write tests for it on your local storage? There's no reason to upload the test files to the production environment. Its not like you are touching the source code this way you just use it as a reference? There literally no way to test something without having access to the files / project. The only thing you could do, is to write API tests if the application has API points. But even this wouldn't make sense? Ask your team how they think you can test an app without access to the files?

Comment: The thing is I have access to the file. What I'm asking if a script which is under a document ready can be tested in rails somehow without change the code making that public. I'm aware of Teaspoon I'm doing tests in it but my office forbid me to do changes in the main code. So I need a way to test without change the code.

Comment: @Jakub what I'd probably do in your case is integrate [webpacker gem](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) into your Rails app. Note though that by default it's already include in Rails 5.1+. Then, I'll write the tests using any node.js tools (because you can now with webpacker): i.e. you can use Rewire -- that you said is what you would have used in node.js. The one gotcha though is that assuming your app is not using webpacker yet, and the JS code are written as part of Rails asset pipeline (i.e. those JS files inside app/assets/javascripts/), then you'd want to auto-compile them first for..

Comment: ... you to be able to "require" them in your tests. You can compile them using [blade](https://github.com/javan/blade), and just configure `.blade.yml` for the output file path for the compiled JS. After compilation, require that output JS file in your JS test files, and use Rewire or any other node.js module as you wish, in order to test what's private in that "required" file. Probably, there should be a better solution, but I'm not too well-versed with JS testing in Rails, but hopefully it helps. You'd probably want to auto-compile the lib file when your test are ran, probably through a CI?

Comment: As an example of what I did before, feel free to check my gem specifically this [file](https://github.com/jrpolidario/live_record/blob/master/lib/assets/compiled/live_record.js). This is an example of `blade` compiled file for all that's contained in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` that uses Sprockets. What I do after compiling is that I just simply `require 'path_to_compiled_file/live_record.js'` for example.

Comment: My CTO told me to test a document ready functions testing the calls. He told me I can check to send some data via URL and check if the call was made and the output. He talked about something to kill the document ready.

Comment: @Jakub hmm if you are required to write this in Rails, unlike what I already suggested above to write in JS (and include modules as needed), then I guess you can try the gem [capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara). I'm not sure if you can mock the JS functions though, but behaviour-wise you can test "what should happen when an event is triggered" (i.e. like your document.ready). This is already feature-testing though and not unit-testing (that I think what you were asking for?). With capybara, you can also `execute_script("someJSCode();")` for example.

Comment: @Jakub [This](https://github.com/jrpolidario/live_record/blob/master/spec/features/live_record_syncing_spec.rb) is a sample feature-test that I wrote using `capybara` and `rspec` if it helps.